# How can other functions have access to Promise values for processing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I am completely stuck. I have no clue how to perform calculations on values return from a database lookup. The values are calculating and added to a register accessed **by other functions**. Therefore I am looking to save and process return Promise values through multiple functions.

I am using a series of promises to pass along database reads, data conversions, until I finally get to where I need to process and store the data for other processes.

**CalculatorEngine.js**

```
import { Component } from 'react';


const NoteService = require('../../services/note-service');

let currentValue = '';
let currentMeasure = '';

class CalculatorEngine extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    currentMeasure = '';
    currentValue = '';

        this.state = {
        notes: [],
        noteDry: [],
        noteWet: [],
        notePastry: []

    };

    this.inputIngredients = this.inputIngredients.bind(this);

}

componentDidMount() {
    //this.inputIngredients();
}

inputIngredients (ingredient, dataBase)  {

console.log('Testing the Input: iteration('+i+') Ingredient: ('+ingredient+')');
            NoteService
                .getMeasure(ingredient, dataBase)
                //.then(notes => {return notes.sugars;})
                .then(notes=> console.log(notes.sugars))   //returned dataBase value (278)
                .catch();

            currentValue += this.state.notes.conversion[currentMeasure];

}
}

export default CalculatorEngine;
```

I want to save these values (e.g. 278) in order to process them. I also want to give these values access to other functions. How do I do this effectively?

From what I know *return notes;* won't work to save and process data because the initial process, .then(), is still pending and has no value.

Await/Async is supposed to allow thus waiting for assigning values, but I cannot get it to work due to a sea of red errors.

I have even tried saving to this.state but the my particular jsx file is still part of the model and has no render(). I earlier received a message saying this.state was inaccessible due to the state not being mounted. So the this.state option seems like a deadend.

In summary: I would like a series of returned values to contribute to different calculations. An example would be to display the ingredient name of the returned value, to calculate a recipe sugar content, etc. and to display some values instantaneously while other values will be displayed after the user has input all ingredients.

[image: Error messages and console.log() messages]

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question/issue.  If you want to return a value from the inputIngredients function, then you have to return it as a promise because you are performing an async operation when calling NoteService.getMeasure().

Comment: `How can other functions have access to Promise values for processing?` the same way you "gave access" to `console.log` to "process" the value

Comment: The question is when I pass that Promise how can I use it in other functions. For example adding the 278 value to a register that other functions will also access. Using promises is appears limited because the scope seems very restricted. Am I right it that assessment?

Comment: You would enjoy learning how to use `await` with promises.  The scope will seem less restricted then.

Comment: note that if `inputIngredients` is asynchronous, you should be returning the `Promise`. Currently you don't have a `return` statement at all. it should probably be `return NoteService.getMeasuer().then().catch();`

Comment: `currentValue += '*';  currentValue += this.state.notes.conversion[currentMeasure];` is the statement that immediately follows the last statement of inputIngredients(). `currentMeasure`  is equal to `C`. I earlier tried to save the return database field in `this.state.notes`. I will edit the post to show this.

Comment: The final goal is to get a value into currentValue. A series of measures will be entered ...wait I am thinking is if save all input into an array then go to the database one time at the end of input with a collection of all input, that may work, i.e. save the processing until the end

Comment: where is `currentMeasure` defined and set? does it depend on the result of calling `NoteService.getMeasure` ?

Comment: No, `currentMeasure` is set by a handler, a button (onClick) pushed by the user (a calculator). Only the `notes` is associated with the database lookup. So the program takes the `onClick()` value of the `currentMeasure` and the ingredient, looks the ingredient up in the database. At this point the note associated with the ingredient is retrieved; this is `notes`. The user submitted `currentMeasure` field is used to obtain a value associated with the ingredient. So each ingredient has a value associated with its unit of measure that has to be obtained.

Comment: What should guarantee that `this.state.notes.conversion[currentMeasure]` is defined?

Comment: So `currentMeasure` is set in another CalculatorEngine component. It's value is obtain from a value passed from a parent file `NoteManager'. `notes` is finally stored at the `NoteService` procedure, it is initiall stored via a mongodb query Promise `.find({_id: currentIngredient})`, it is passed via a database lookup where it goes through subsequent json/data/router etc conversions. The `notes` are all the same. `.then(notes=> {return notes})` is the database entry. The state storage of `notes` fails because there is no render() to mount `notes. I render in the parent file.

Comment: `this.state.notes.conversion[currentMeasure]` is guranteed to have a value because the user presses a calculator key pad, so all inputs are preknown. All the restricted values are stored in the database where information is only read not added or deleted.

Comment: the error you got (cannot read property 'C' of undefined) indicates that `this.state.notes.conversion` was undefined. Do you know how that happened?

Comment: Yes. Previously, I tried to assign the database entry to `this.setState={notes}` in the '.then' Promise chain but I couldn't do it because of an error _Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted._ I think this means I have to reference 'this.state.notes' via a render() call. So the error is basically because I am trying access via '[currentMeasure]' a state that is undefined.

Comment: Conclusion: I could only access `notes` in the view HTML, but I could not make it accessible to other functions in my implementations.